# Save PDF/A with Chrome headless

Tags: pdf, google-chrome-headless, html-to-pdf

Is it possible to save PDF/A file with Chrome headless? If not, is there any library that allows this in node?

Or maybe it is possible to say "I'm generating" PDF/A file with some considerations, like embedding fonts or no dynamic content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Chrome headless does not have way to save PDF/A.
However you can use a PDF to PDF/A conversion tool to get the job done (there is a free online tool from https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-tools/pdfa-converter)